# Add 2 dataframe with dfifferent lengths in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the above 2 dataframes in R,

```
df1 = [a,2      df2 = [a,10
      b,3]             c,2]
```

I want to add those 2 df, so the output can be

```
df = [a, 12,
      b, 3,
      c, 2]
```

Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `rbind` the two datasets and do a group by sum

```
aggregate(col2 ~ col1, rbind(df1, df2), sum)
```

-output

```
#   col1 col2
#1    a   12
#2    b    3
#3    c    2
```

---

Or in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
     group_by(col1) %>%
     summarise(col2 = sum(col2), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  col1   col2
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 a        12
#2 b         3
#3 c         2
```

#### data

```
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = c('a', 'c'), col2 = c(10, 2))
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c('a', 'b'), col2 = c(2, 3))
```